# Laravel 5.4 array validation as single field message

Tags: laravel, validation

I have following situation, the problem is validation error occurring twice because there are two different fields. The requirement is, there should be only once *"User is  required."*

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="user[]" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" name="user[]" placeholder="Last Name">
```

**Form Request:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user.*' => 'required|min:3',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'user.*' => 'User is required',
    ];
}
```

**Validation Output**:

```
/**
 * User is required field.
 * User is required field.
 */
```

Comment: try with 'user.0'     =>  'required',

Comment: No, it won't help me, I want a user to fill both fields but if user skip first-name or last-name validation error message should be "User is required".

Comment: I have answered my question if anyone has other best way... please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an urgent task so I have done it as follows.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="user_data[]" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" name="user_data[]" placeholder="Last Name">
```

**Form Request:**

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = \Request::input('user_data');

    $rules = [];

    if ($user[0] === null || $user[1] === null) {
        $rules['user'] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'user.required' => 'User is required'
    ];
}
```

**Validation Output**:

```
/**
 * User is required
 */
```

Answer (score -3):

Well,  the request itself contains two fields named user[], and thus will validate the field twice.
What you can do is, make two text fields

```
    firstName
    lastName
```

Then before saving, make

```
$fullname=$request->firstName().' '.$request->lastName();
$user->user=$fullname;
$user->save();
```

Comment: the question asking about array validation !

Comment: Please try to understand the question.

Comment: The request treats user [] input as TWO fields, this validation goes through them TWICE.